# PTIJ: is Mi Yodeya found in the Torah codes?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code):

> The Bible code, also known as the Torah code, is a purported set of secret messages encoded within the Hebrew text of the Torah. This hidden code has been described as a method by which specific letters from the text can be selected to reveal an otherwise obscured message.

Have searchers found any codes which mention Mi Yodeya?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: No. [Torah codes are bogus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95446/). Oh, this is PTIJ? Oh, okay, carry on, then.

Answer (score 9):

It's a little difficult to find, but if you know the correct pattern and where to start, you could actually find Mi Yodeya explicitly hinted to within Tanach.

The pattern is to look at every first letter starting from the [21st book of Tanach, fourth chapter, 14th verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), 67th letter. It completely boggled my mind the first time I saw it!

Answer (score -2):

Mi Yodeya is found seven times in the Tanach.

שמואל ב 12:22
ויאמר בעוד הילד חי צמתי ואבכה כי אמרתי מי יודע יחנני יהוה וחי הילד

יואל 2:14
מי יודע ישוב ונחם והשאיר אחריו ברכה מנחה ונסך ליהוה אלהיכם

יונה 3:9
מי יודע ישוב ונחם האלהים ושב מחרון אפו ולא נאבד

תהילים 90:11
מי יודע עז אפך וכיראתך עברתך

משלי 24:22
כי פתאם יקום אידם ופיד שניהם מי יודע

קוהלת 3:21
מי יודע רוח בני האדם העלה היא למעלה ורוח הבהמה הירדת היא למטה לארץ

קוהלת 6:12
כי מי יודע מה טוב לאדם בחיים מספר ימי חיי הבלו ויעשם כצל אשר מי יגיד לאדם מה יהיה אחריו תחת השמש

U'Mi Yodeya is found three times in Tanach.

קוהלת 2:19
ומי יודע החכם יהיה או סכל וישלט בכל עמלי שעמלתי ושחכמתי תחת השמש גם זה הבל

קוהלת 8:1
מי כהחכם ומי יודע פשר דבר חכמת אדם תאיר פניו ועז פניו ישנא

אסתר 4:14
כי אם החרש תחרישי בעת הזאת רוח והצלה יעמוד ליהודים ממקום אחר ואת ובית אביך תאבדו ומי יודע אם לעת כזאת הגעת למלכות

Comment: Those aren't Torah codes.