# Tools to validate Torah codes

Tags: product-recommendation, number, tanach

Torah codes are "a purported set of secret messages encoded within the Hebrew text of the Torah" ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code)).

For instance, a well known code suggests that counting 3 intervals of 12111 letters from the first regular *mem* before the only word whose letters spell the name "Esther" in Chumash ([Bereshit 4:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) result in the word "Megilat" (12111 being the number of letters in Megilat Esther).

Similar codes [were suggested](https://parsha.blogspot.com/2013/02/torah-codes-in-megillat-esther.html) skipping 12196 letters to find Mordechai and Esther, while [others](https://www.mayimachronim.com/are-torah-codes-legit/) write this doesn't work.

**Are there open access tools to validate such codes in the Torah or Tanakh?** An ideal validation tool would generate words from a starting letter and an interval. Bonus would be to count the letters in a part of Tanakh.

Note that I am **not** asking about the overall issues with Torah codes (on which much was written), nor am I asking if the above codes are correct.

Comment: Good point. I find it strange how great the discrepancies in counts are (though I guess I shouldn't considering [the evidence](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97160/3) we've seen of how hard counting can be, and variations and _k'ri uch'siv_, etc. When you say "validate" you just mean to take a starting letter, interval and length as input and return the string produced, not calculate the likelihood of the target string emerging from those parameters against the null hypothesis, right?

Comment: Exactly. The simpler version. Ideally it would be user friendly for non rocket scientists

Comment: I suppose only _k'ri_ would be taken into account and that nobody would count spaces as characters. Are there conventions about which spellings/which _m'sora_ to use where for code finding?

Comment: Note there are different traditions for how many letters are in Esther, so you should also use your tool to see which text it used.

Comment: FWIW, anyone who wants to talk about the validity of Torah codes can take it [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95443/). [IMO](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100767/ptij-is-mi-yodeya-found-in-the-torah-codes#comment336571_100767) Torah codes are only useful for PTIJ.

Comment: According to https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.30a.13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Torah codes are a complete hoax. The Rabbis fully admit the scrolls we have aren't "original"

Answer (score 5):

TorahBibleCodes is a Free, Open-Source Python Project that enables you to search for hidden Torah Bible Codes in the Hebrew Torah and Bible. We offer a simple and intuitive App (and API) that is both free and open-source.

Please visit our web site, GitHub, StackOverflow, YouTube, Rumble, Twitter, and GiveSendGo.

HOMEPAGE URL: https://TorahBibleCodes.com

GITHUB: https://github.com/torahbiblecodes

READTHEDOCS (this page): https://torahbiblecodes-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

ACADEMIA: https://www.academia.edu/104334275

STACKOVERFLOW: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8911652/torahbiblecodes

TWITTER: @TorahBibleCodes https://twitter.com/TorahBibleCodes

YOUTUBE: @TorahBibleCodes https://www.youtube.com/@TorahBibleCodes

YOUTUBE: @TorahBibleCodes https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNsvtMx4JJRpNzzPq57HCqg

GIVESENDGO: @TorahBibleCodes https://www.givesendgo.com/torahbiblecodes

Comment: Does the code let you adjust the text you are searching through?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "adjust". The code lets you choose the text(s) you wish to search; The code is free and open-source, so certainly if you know Python you can "adjust" and develop in any way you intend.  [link] (https://torahbiblecodes-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: Link to academic paper dropped that explains the TorahBibleCodes software (and research data) available - thank you in advance for your patience as I will update the GitHub with the most current software version with ELS Search Capabilities to share with the world asap: 

https://www.academia.edu/104334275